# Navigate to other pages google apps script UiApp

Tags: google-apps-script

Can someone explain to me how to go about navigating to a new page in google apps script is done ? My initial thought is to hide or delete all child elements within the app and then rebuild it accordingly. Is this the right approach ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using UiApp or HtmlService?

Comment: @Arun - I'm using UiApp, edited the question for clarity. thanks

Comment: And one more question - are you deploying this as a Web App or diplaying this UI within a spreadsheet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Srik already arrived one very common approach for page navigation/organization.

Here is another way using a query string attribute to fork off to a different UI path. This has the added benefit of getting the activity "spinner".

You can see it in action at this link below with the code powering it underneath it. Hope this provides another perspective.

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx68wR5HmCbil_LY8LlMd2m16_xNEdEtXq7-YfgqsMPqeoe-E3L/exec

```
function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var page = e.parameter.page

  //add a default page
  if(!page){
    page = '1';  
  }

  if(page === '1'){
    var label = app.createLabel('You are in page 1.')

    var anchor = app.createAnchor("Next page",ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()+"?page=2");
    anchor.setTarget('_self');

    app.add(label);
    app.add(anchor);
  }
  else if(page === '2'){
    var label = app.createLabel('You are in page 2, now.')

    var anchor = app.createAnchor("Go back",ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()+"?page=1");
    anchor.setTarget('_self');

    app.add(label);
    app.add(anchor);
  }

  return app;
}
```

Comment: @Arun : the advantage of the activity "spinner" is also an inconvenient since it's not very fast... but apart from that this is indeed quite smart and original ;-) thanks for the info.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to have different panels representing different pages. Initially hide all but the first page and then unhide subsequent pages

Comment: Is there a way of hiding all elements in an app, maybe a function ?

Comment: The best way is to compartmentalize your UI design so that UI elements are grouped based on when they have to be visible / invisible. Add each of these groups to a different panel.And set visibility on the panel to true/false

Comment: The other advantage of this multipanel approach is that you can use clientHandlers to switch from one panel to the other and so get a very fast and responsive behavior since the whole app is loaded at once when you call the app. see illustration [here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxlPTVLSLfO3d1w2vSrMzzh57p9DJM6ivCIHiIfTB2AKqubSs1L/exec)