# Direct to another URL using a server side handler

Tags: google-apps-script

I am looking for a way to navigate to a URL using a button in my Google Apps Script UiApp. I have added an on click server handler to the button, and once the event is triggered I would like to navigate to a different URL.

Is there a way I can do this in a server side handler ?

Many thanks

Comment: you could also have a look at [this recent post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13585750/navigate-to-other-pages-google-apps-script-uiapp)

Comment: I did implement this method however I need to handle the url from within a server side handler, hence this question is specific to server handlers. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relax_Im_A_Quant there is no way to have a server handler send the user to another URL. They have to click on a link.

However, there is a way to achieve similar results and may suit your needs.

You can add, remove and change the visibility of the elements in your UiApp.

For example, have a search box that starts visible and a results panel that starts not visible. When the server handler is called the search box is changed to not visible, the results panel changed to visible and the results are added to the results panel. You can turn off the visibility of a whole panel and turn on the visibility of a another.

In one of my apps that creates a document for the user, it would add a link to the document to the UiApp and then make it visible when the 'create document' button was pressed. It would prompt the user to click the link after it appeared -- taking them to the document (a new URL).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer - yes I think this is definitely the way to go here. Am I right in thinking this would have performance benefits as well, not having to reload previously loaded panels ? thanks again

Comment: Relax_Im_A_Quant, yes and no. If the user uses each panel a number of times and few are not used, probably yes. But, if you only use a few of the panels and many could go unused, probably no. You are betting on the user using/reusing the loaded panels at least once each.