"You need access" error when changing or adding the query selector in Google Apps Script
I was trying to make a simple webpage in app script and I wanted to add a query selector so it will change the page accordingly but it just doesn't want to work.
Index.js
      var url = "";
    function saveData(name) {
        const data =  name ;
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function() {
  if (url) {
    const newUrl = url + '?page=bid';

    // Navigate to the new page content
    window.open(newUrl, "_self");
  } else {
    console.log("URL not set yet.");
  }
            }).saveData(data, "bids");
    }
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(e){
      url = e;
    }).getLink();

Code.gs
function doGet(e) {
  if (e.queryString !== '') {
    switch (e.parameter.page) {
      case 'bid':
        return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("bid")
          .setTitle("Bids")
          .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
      case 'add':
        return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("addition")
          .setTitle("Add new")
          .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);

    }

  }
  else {

    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("home")
      .setTitle("Home")
      .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
  }
}

function getLink() {
  return ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();

}

I tried using different ways to navigate to a new page, but the only one that worked was winddow.open(newUrl, "_blank"); which I don't want to resort to (the rest would give the you need access page, even though I'm using the correct account). Is there any way of doing this?

This question is similar to: How to navigate html pages with standalone Google Apps Script?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Did you have chance to look at this as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13585750/navigate-to-other-pages
